How do we determine whether a body is in equillibrium?
For instance, I was solving a problem related to friction (newtons laws of motion) and in the question, a block with a mass 'm' was being pulled at an angle 'α' with horizontal with a certain force 'F'. The forces acting on it are normal force 'N', and friction force 'f'. Now, since the force with which the block is being pulled is at  angle α, we know that the force has to be split into it's certain components. What I don't understand though, is how the system is under equilibrium? (That is how the question is solved, by equating Fcosα to f and Fsinα + N = mg. ) Shouldn't we use ∑F=ma and solve the question?

"Equilibrium" has a definition:

When the net external force acting on a particle is zero, the particle is said to be in equilibrium.

(This assumes no rotation.)
If your block is in equilibrium, you should be able to find forces such that the vector sum of all of them add to zero. You allude to three forces: the normal force, the friction force, and the force at which the block is being pulled at. All three point in different directions, so it is possible for them to sum to zero.
You could use $\sum F = ma$ to solve the question, or $\sum F_x = ma_x$ + $\sum F_y = ma_y$. The latter just breaks down the vector sum into two directions, the horizontal and vertical, and require that they are both zero (which is functionally the same as requiring the vector sum to be zero, since $\vec{0}$ implies that there is no net force in any direction). That appears to be what your answer key appears to have done.
